# Erro de conversão no método Deserialize do RestSharp

Tags: c#, exceção

Eu tenho um método que consome um Rest e depois deserializa utilizando uma classe. Estava funcionando, mas talvez pela mudança do retorno tenha feito aparecer o erro.

O meu método está assim:

```
public void LoadPedidos()
{
    var client = new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url_client"]);
    var request = new RestRequest(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["req_Pedidos"], Method.POST);

    request.AddParameter("loja_evento", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["loja_evento"]);
    request.AddParameter("usuario", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["usuario"]);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
    var des = deserial.Deserialize<Pedidos>(response);

    int credito = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["credito"]);
    int debito = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["debito"]);

    Console.WriteLine(des.status);
    Console.WriteLine(des.itens);
}
```

E minha classe Pedidos:

```
public class Pagto
{
    public int id_pedido_pagamento { get; set; }
    public int id_forma_de_pagamento { get; set; }
    public decimal valor { get; set; }        
    public int parcelas { get; set; }
}

public class Iten
{
    public string pedido { get; set; }
    public string cliente { get; set; }        
    public List<Pagto> pagtos { get; set; }        
}

public class Pedidos
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public List<Iten> itens { get; set; }
}
```

No entanto, está retornando um erro de conversão do tipo string para o tipo datetime.

O erro é esse:

> ```
> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato correto.
> ```

Exemplo de retorno do rest:

```
{
"status":true,
"itens":[
  {
     "pedido":"562-SERVER_HOM",
     "cliente":"",
     "pagtos":[
        {
           "id_pedido_pagamento":"537",
           "id_forma_de_pagamento":"2",
           "valor":"189.00",
           "parcelas":"4"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "pedido":"564-SERVER_HOM",
     "cliente":"",
     "pagtos":[
        {
           "id_pedido_pagamento":"538",
           "id_forma_de_pagamento":"2",
           "valor":"90.00",
           "parcelas":"2"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "pedido":"571-SERVER_HOM",
     "cliente":"",
     "pagtos":[
        {
           "id_pedido_pagamento":"539",
           "id_forma_de_pagamento":"5",
           "valor":"189.00"
        }
     ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Em qual linha estoura o erro?

Comment: var des = deserial.Deserialize<Pedidos>(response);

Comment: Qual é o item que ele está processando quando dá o erro?